# Nokogiri ignores utf-8 setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, centos, nokogiri

I will describe my issue with few liens of code

```
irb(main):004:0> require 'nokogiri'
=> true
irb(main):005:0> builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8'){ |xml| xml.root { xml.Test "Täht" } }
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Builder:0x961a374 @ns=nil, @arity=1, @parent=#         <Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x4b0cf30 name="document" children=[#  <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x4b0ce40 name="root" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x4b0cd50 name="Test" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x4b0c7a6 "T\303\244ht">]>]>]>, @context=nil, @doc=#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x4b0cf30 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x4b0ce40 name="root" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x4b0cd50 name="Test" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x4b0c7a6 "T\303\244ht">]>]>]>>
irb(main):009:0> builder.to_xml(:encoding => 'utf-8')
=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<root>\n  <Test>T&#xE4;ht</Test>\n</root>\n"
```

There is strange environment specific behaviour, even if I define utf-8 encoding it still uses html entities.

- CentOS release 5.8 (Final)
- ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03
- Rails 3.2.11

Same code on mac works fine.

Comment: I would request you to go [`nokogiri-talk`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nokogiri-talk). Very active, and the project owners are there..available

Comment: I have found roots of issue:
1. Update CentOS libxml2 up to 2.7 version
2. Set file write mode in ruby to "w:UTF-8"

Comment: post it as an answer, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found roots of issue:

- Update CentOS libxml2 up to 2.7 version
- Set file write mode in ruby
  to "w:UTF-8"